# to_csv，Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set and copy_from StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying load my pandas dataframe ot postgressql db with psycopg2.
So, here is what I am doing.

```
dft.to_csv(tmp_csv, header=False,index = False,sep='\x1f',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar='')
f = open(tmp_csv, 'r')
cur.copy_from(f, tableName, null='', sep='\x1f',columns=(colNames)) # loading to postgres
```

However it gives Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set for one of the row.
So, I assume that the hex char '1f' is coming some where in the data and causing this problem.
Its a very long row with around 1500 columns. So, I couldn't exactly pin point it. But, I will not be having control on this data. So, what ever delimiter I use , it may come in data in future.
Then I tried to remove such chars from my df with below code.

```
dft = dft.replace('\x1f','', regex=True)
```

But that didn't help. Still gave Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set.

Then I tried using escape char to solve the issue.

```
dft.to_csv(tmp_csv, header=False,index = False,sep='\x1f',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar='',escapechar='\x2f')
f = open(tmp_csv, 'r')
cur.copy_from(f, tableName, null='', sep='\x1f',columns=(colNames)) # loading to postgres
```

But then I get long field error in the postgres copy.

```
StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character(10)
CONTEXT:  COPY postgres_tbl, line 11, column strength_unit_txt: "50 MCG//0.5"
```

So, I assume that pandas adding a new char while writing csv as escape. But Postgres counting this  char also and the field length is getting increased to give this error.
Any idea, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: try using `\x1f` as escape char. `cursor.copy_from` does not mention the escape char (see https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/397) but in the docs there is link to [this](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#copy) and there is [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) where it says the default value for ESCAPE is the same as QUOTE.

Comment: Which character do you think pandas added?  It seems to me that the simpler explanation is that your data is actually too big to fit in the column type provided to hold it.